# Problema com OpenShift + Mentawai

Tags: java, openshift, i18n

Estou com um problema em relação ao OpenShift. Já subi minha aplicação (java/jsp) e meu banco (postgresql) e parece estar Ok.

O problema é que utilizo o mentawai como framework mvc e a aplicação não está encontrando as lists e internacionalização i18n.

O endereço da app é este: http://artilheiropro-apro.rhcloud.com/

Já pesquisei em vários lugares mas não encontrei nada relativo a isso! Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que parece você não está enviando para a JSP sua lista e com isso a *tag* mtw na página fica quebrada.
No método correspondente que invoca sua página você deve enviar a lista posições via "output".

Exemplo:

```
output.setValue("posicoes", posicoes);
```

Esse código deverá ser colocado antes da sua consequência *SUCCESS*.

Comment: Acredito que não seja isso pois essa aplicação local funciona perfeitamente. Inclusive em outro servidor também (www.artilheiroPro.com). O problema só acontece no OpenShift. Acredito que possa ser alguma configuração específica de lá, mas não consigo encontrar nada a respeito.